# Codeigniter Inter Controller Communication

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, controller

I am new to MVC, CodeIginter. Instead of getting things easy, it needs lot of code to be written for a simple application. These are might be happening becouse I am new. So I have few confusions about this thing. Any kind of help is appreciated.
1) Methods are written in one controller can not be accessed in another controller classes. I have to write a new function for the same functionality.

2) To create website administration panel (back-end) in none mvc panel, we usually create it in a new folder. Is this thing possible in CodeIgniter? If not what about the admin (back-end)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to clear some of your doubts about this.

1) Calling a controller's method from another controller is not possible, and it's whtouth meaning by the way.

A controller is supposed to get an action from the URL (which is routed by CI to the right controller for the task) and, based on that, decide which Model and which model's method needs be called to elaborate the data requested.

The model, then, hands back the result of this elaboration to the controller, which , in turns, decides to which view pass this results.

The view, eventually, is structured to get those datas and display them.

SO, as you can see, calling a controllers' method from another controller is nonsense, it would be like going to a page and finding another one instead; if you want to pass to another controller the request...well, there's the redirect for that.

If you find out you have the same functionalities in several moment, think twice:

1. What is a funcionality? Do you mean somehtin like "display posts" in controller "archive" and "display posts" in controller "news" ? they're hardly the same functionality; they can maybe share views, or models, but that's it.
2. For functions that doesn't relate to URLs, but involve some further elaboration (which might be wrong to do in Models) and are nonetheless called in a controller, you have library instead. Think at the "form_validation" library, which is called in a controller's method, but has its own peculiar (and encapsulated) functionalies. Ora a "session" library, or an "authentication" library

2) To create an admin panel the easiest thing is: create an "admin" controller (which is accesible then to www.mysite.com/index.php/admin), and put all the administration actions there, in its methods: create_page(), edit_page(), manage_users(), whatever.
In order to avoid people accessing it freely you need to build an authentication system, which, in its simplest and barabone strucutre, might be a check of wheter a session is set or not (maybe a check done at __construct() time).

But you can find nice Auth libraries out there already made, such as Ion Auth or Tank Auth (the 2 most popular to my knowledge)

Hope things are a bit clearer now. See also Interstellar_Coder's comment at this answer if you're interested in the modular HMVC approach.

Comment: Actually using the new HMVC pattern you could theoretically call another controller method from one controller. This seems to be a growing trend and helps further separate code, internally the request is mimicked and the output from the view is returned and can be used in conjuction to the view for the current controller. Although in this specific case i don't think the OP needs to use this approach.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I know, but I assumed OP was still missing some of the basics, so I thought that mentioning HMVC (which is not native in CodeIgniter, also) would be a step further still not necessary and that could generate even more confusion. Thanks a lot for the addition, though.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Methods are written in one controller can not be accessed in another controller classes. I have to write a new function for the same functionality.

What's the functionality about? Perhaps you should write a library/helper instead, controller's logic should be limited to request flow or something else but not too complicated. For that, put the functionality in the model, or if more general, in library/helper.

> 2) To create website administration panel (back-end) in none mvc panel, we usually create it in a new folder. Is this thing possible in CodeIgniter? If not what about the admin (back-end)??

I don't get it, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. 
Admin panel means the section of website where content etc is modified by accessing database etc.
For example my site is "mysite.com" and amdin panel is "mysite.com/admin"

Comment: that happens almost all the time, it should be handled just by another controller, just like the others. which part makes you confused?